# Samsung Galaxy Ace keeps updating Samsung app store

Tags: applications, updates, samsung-galaxy-ace

I recently purchased a Samsung Galaxy Ace and tried to get onto the Samsung application store on the phone. 
It said that there was an update for the application so I downloaded it and tried to get into the application again. 
It again came up with the update option and it keeps repeating the process...

Please can I have an answer for this as I'm not familiar with these kinds of phones...

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the Samsung app store required me to install 3 updates before I could use it when I bought my Samsung Galaxy S2. I browsed it once and then never looked at it again because it hardly has any interesting apps. So if I were you, I wouldn't bother with the Samsung app store update, just use Google Play.